# Helper app for 3rd party OS X app

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing-entitlements

I currently working on a small GUI helper which is a wrapper for a command line utility from another company.

Everything works fine when sandboxing is disabled. But as I want to distribute the app via the App Store I need to enable sandboxing.

When I open my app the first time the user can simply drag&drop the 3rd party CLI tool to configure the helper. In the background I am copying the CLI tool in my apps sandbox folder.

The 3rd party app has its own entitlement.

I am executing the command via NStask.
When I do this in sandbox mode I get the error:

```
exec of /Users/xxxx/Library/Containers/com.xxxxxx/Data/Library/Application Support/YYYYY Helper/YYYY denied since it was quarantined by YYYYY Helper and not approved by Gatekeeper, qtn-flags was 0x00000002
```

I googelt around but didn't find much about this.
Would be great if anyone has an idea on how to fix it.

Thanks
Sascha